# Why I cannot set the labels with the data passed from one UIViewController to another (printing the data in console works) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

In my app I have an embedded UIViewController inside a container. In my story board I added a touch event to this viewcontroller and I called the segue: `fullRequestSegue`

Then in the code of that UIViewController I wrote:

```
class RequestDetails: UIViewController, ShowRequestDetailsFromMap {

var fullRequestDetails: FullRequestFromMap?

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
if (segue.identifier == "fullRequestSegue"){
    fullRequestDetails?.changeEventDescr(self.descr, username: "adam", number: "12", created_at: self.created_at, photo: self.photo)

        fullRequestDetails = segue.destinationViewController as? FullRequestFromMap
        fullRequestDetails!.showRequestDetails = self      
    }
}
}
```

Then in my class `FullRequestFromMap` I have:

```
protocol ShowRequestDetailsFromMap {
    func changeEventDescr(text:String)
}

class FullRequestFromMap: UIViewController{

@IBOutlet weak var userNumber: UILabel!
var showRequestDetails:ShowRequestDetailsFromMap?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func changeEventDescr(description: String, username: String, number: String, created_at: NSDate, photo: String) {

    print(username)
    print(description)
    print(number)
    print(created_at)
    print(photo) //that works fine, I see all valid data in the console

    userNumber.text = number //doesn't work, I see empty label instead of filled with passed data, the same problem is with other labels

}
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: you try alloc and init that class like this :-
var showRequestDetails:ShowRequestDetailsFromMap = ShowRequestDetailsFromMap ()

=> then it might be work..try it...

Comment: Ok I tried that but I'm getting this error http://imgur.com/zdmwPRn

Comment: are getting in log value of that number in consol ? have you debug it ?

Comment: My problem here is that even when I write `userNumber.text = "aaaa"` in the method `changeEventDescr` then the label does not get updated... I don't know what might be the issue here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when the method `changeEventDescr` is called the `userNumber` label is not initialized. You are trying to assign to a nil object.

Create a string variable in your `FullRequestFromMap` class and store text in it and in your `viewDidLoad` method you have to assign the text to `userNumber` label.

```
class FullRequestFromMap: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var userNumber: UILabel!
    var showRequestDetails:ShowRequestDetailsFromMap?

    var userNumberLabelText:String = "Default Value"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        userNumber.text = userNumberLabelText
    }

    func changeEventDescr(description: String, username: String, number: String, created_at: NSDate, photo: String) {

        print(username)
        print(description)
        print(number)
        print(created_at)
        print(photo)

        userNumberLabelText = number // Here you set the class variable, not the label it self
    }
}

class RequestDetails: UIViewController {
    ......

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if (segue.identifier == "fullRequestSegue") {
            fullRequestDetails = segue.destinationViewController as? FullRequestFromMap

            // Option 1: You can directly assign it
            fullRequestDetails?.userNumberLabelText = "12"

            // Option 2: You can call your method
            fullRequestDetails?.changeEventDescr(self.descr, username: "adam", number: "12", created_at: self.created_at, photo: self.photo)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wait, I hope I understand it clearly - should I create a random string variable (`var text = "sth"`), then assign it to my label in viewDidLoad() (`userNumber.text = text`) and then put the line `userNumber.text = number` again in `changeEventDescr` function?

Comment: @user3766930 I have edited the answer. Please check now